# css aspect-ratio and -webkit-aspect-ratio not working

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, aspect-ratio

I'm building an app on a modified **Webkit 2.34** and I've tried everything I could to keep a div within a ratio of 48/9. Aspect-ratio property seems to work with chromium but not on webkit. Even when using -webkit-aspect-ratio it doesn't keep render the good way. 
I couldn't find any help on -webkit-aspect-ratio

Anyone could explain me why it's not working.
Thanks !